Issues Sending Data from JavaScript to C# via Native Messaging
I’m trying to send data from JavaScript (in a Chrome extension) to a C# application using Native Messaging, but it’s not working as expected.
Here’s my JavaScript code:
Copiar código
const dados = {
    nome: "João",
    idade: 30
};

chrome.runtime.sendNativeMessage(
    'com.my_company.my_application',
    dados,
    function(response) {
        if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
            console.error("Error communicating with the native host:", chrome.runtime.lastError);
        } else {
            console.log('Response received: ', response);
        }
    }
);

And here's my C# code for the native messaging host:
using (var server = new NamedPipeServerStream("com.my_company.my_application", PipeDirection.InOut))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Waiting for connection...");
    server.WaitForConnection();

    using (var reader = new StreamReader(server, Encoding.UTF8))
    {
        string message = reader.ReadToEnd();
        Console.WriteLine("Message received: " + message);
    }
}

When I check the message received on the C# side, it’s just chrome-extension://<>, and the DevTools console shows an error: "Error when communicating with the native messaging host."
I know the communication is happening because I get the Chrome extension ID, but the actual data isn't being passed.
What could be causing this issue? How can I properly send the data from JavaScript to C#?
I what receive message = {
nome: "João",
idade: 30
};

Native messaging API does not use named pipes, it uses stdin/stdout. Each message starts with 4 bytes of its length. Is this code from ChatGPT? If so, it hallucinates, so find an example for C#.

You probably want to tag this with chrome-native-messaging

No, it's not from ChatGPT, but rather an adaptation that I already had. I couldn't find anything in C#, in the Google documentation https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/develop/concepts/native-messaging it says: "Windows-only: Make sure that the program's I/O mode is set to O_BINARY. By default, the I/O mode is O_TEXT, which corrupts the message format as line breaks (\n = 0A) are replaced with Windows-style line endings (\r\n = 0D 0A). The I/O mode can be set using __setmode." But I've already tested reading it in binary format and the answer is the same.

The woxxom
Is totally right.
The c# must be like this:
private static async Task Main(string[] args)
 {

     JObject data;
     while ((data = Read()) != null)
     {
         var processed = ProcessMessage(data);
     }
 }

public static string ProcessMessage(JObject data)
{
    var message = data["text"].Value<string>();
    switch (message)
    {
        case "test":
            return "testing!";
        case "exit":
            return "exit";
        default:
            return "echo: " + message;
    }
}

public static JObject Read()
{
    var stdin = Console.OpenStandardInput();
    var length = 0;

    var lengthBytes = new byte[4];
    stdin.Read(lengthBytes, 0, 4);
    length = BitConverter.ToInt32(lengthBytes, 0);

    var buffer = new char[length];
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(stdin))
    {
        while (reader.Peek() >= 0)
        {
            reader.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        }
    }

    return (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(new string(buffer));
}

